# How to input a list to the embedding layer?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have three Inputs which are concatenated later.
Two of those inputs are of the shape (1,) but the 3rd one is a list itself (25 elements per list). 
I am trying to input these 3 to an embedding layer. But the 3rd one (which is a list) produces an error : ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

```
def rec(n_users, n_movies, n_factors, min_rating, max_rating):

    user = Input(shape=(1,))
    u = Embedding(n_users, n_factors, embeddings_initializer='he_normal',
                  embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6))(user)
    u = Reshape((n_factors,))(u)

    movie = Input(shape=(1,))
    m = Embedding(n_movies, n_factors, embeddings_initializer='he_normal',
                  embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6))(movie)
    m = Reshape((n_factors,))(m)

    tags = Input(shape=(25,))
    t = Embedding(500, n_factors)(tags)
    t = Reshape((n_factors,))(t)

    x = Concatenate()([u, m, t])
    x = Dropout(0.05)(x)

    x = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

    x = Lambda(lambda x: x * (max_rating - min_rating) + min_rating)(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[user, movie, tags], outputs=x)
    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
    return model
```

X_train_array looks like this:

```
[array([ 90, 291, 473, ..., 479,   5, 102], dtype=int64),
 array([1829,   98, 1321, ..., 4601,  748, 4522], dtype=int64),
 array([[  0,   0,   0, ..., 401, 201, 100],
        [  0,   0,   0, ..., 235, 100, 385],
        [  0,   0,   0, ..., 439, 487, 385],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0, ..., 471, 235, 100],
        [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0, 100],
        [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0, 221]], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: This model compiled fine on TF 1.15. Do you still have the error? If so, at which line of code do you get this?

Comment: @thushv89 t = Reshape((n_factors,))(t) is the line.. says ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: I see. Well now it makes sense. For `u` and `m` you have a single inputs but for `t` it's 25 so obviously `t` cannot be reshaped to the same size `u` and `m` will be reshaped to. Can you tell me the size of the output you expect after each reshape?

Comment: @thushv89 1,50 is what I would like..

Comment: I need more info than that, `u` and `m` will have `[None, 50]` outputs, but the problem is `t`. It will have a `[None, 25, 50]` sized output. So if you need a `[None,1,50]` output you need to reduce (e.g. average) your embeddings for `t` over the time dimension. Is that what you need.

Comment: @thushv89 Thank you so much for trying to help me.. What I'm trying to achieve is, **u** is the user and **m** is the movie. **t** has tags and genres mixed together. I one hot encoded the tags and i would like my model to learn about the the **tags and genres** simultaneously. I'm still a beginner and I'm sorry if this comes off as amateurish.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's just that I am still a bit unclear what you exactly need. I'll may be post an answer of what I think you need as the solution. And if any edits are required, we can go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's my proposal for you. Here's a depiction of my solution. You can see that the problem is where the question marks are. You need to perform some transformation at this point to be able to concatenate and get a `[None, 150]`.

[image]
Btw, note that I did a few minor changes (which shouldn't affect the correctness of the solution).

- Removed the `l2` regularization
- Instead of creating `Adam` optimizer, passing string `'adam'` to the optimizer argument

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def rec(n_users, n_movies, n_factors, min_rating, max_rating):

    user = Input(shape=(1,))
    u = Embedding(n_users, n_factors, embeddings_initializer='he_normal')(user)
    u = Reshape((n_factors,))(u)

    movie = Input(shape=(1,))
    m = Embedding(n_movies, n_factors, embeddings_initializer='he_normal')(movie)
    m = Reshape((n_factors,))(m)

    tags = Input(shape=(25,))
    t = Embedding(500, n_factors)(tags)
    t = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1))(t)

    x = Concatenate()([u, m, t])
    x = Dropout(0.05)(x)

    x = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

    x = Lambda(lambda x: x * (max_rating - min_rating) + min_rating)(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[user, movie, tags], outputs=x)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Comment: It worked!! Thankyou so much! Really appreciate it. Very concise and helpful! One last thing, is there any other better approach for this same problem statement? i.e. Movie Recommendation taking into account the user, movie and tags+genres.

Comment: @ashishjohn, so when I proposed the solution, I was merely looking at the architecture of the model. To provide an opinion on what you asked, I need more info (maybe an example too) of what you're trying to solve. PS: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it SO etiquette :)

Comment: I'm still new to the website so I wasn't really aware of the accept feature haha.. obviously very happy and satisfied with your answer.. selected now!

Comment: About what I'm trying to do now.. I would like to train my model only with the metadata column so that the model recommends me movies . I was thinking I'd use rnn or lstm for the after embedding. But how do I recommend multiple movies ? Thankyou once again.. :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to go with a [Recommender Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) approach?

Comment: No @thushv89.. I'd like to recommend movies based on tags and genre alone.. I'll not consider the ratings also. I'll input tags and the output will be corresponding movies matching those tags . Maybe multiple movies sharing similar tags.

Comment: @ashishjohn, In that case, you can try changing the last layer to `Dense(n_movies, activation='sigmoid')` and use `binary_crossentropy` as the loss. That's how multi-class classification done in keras [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10371). But you might run in to memory issues if the number of movies is very large. In this case, you might want to look in to  [negative sampling loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss)

Comment: But there are 9742 movies.. and after padding all the tags+genres, the input vector turns into 1569 elements per movie.. I still went ahead and tried what you suggested.. As soon as the training starts, accuracy jumps to 99% and the predictions for test samples are all almost the same..